# Split file into multiple files one row at a time

Tags: bash, awk, grep, cut

I have a log file (about 50K rows) in the format:

```
email1@gmail.com:address0:some_details0
email2@gmail.com:address1:some_details1
email1@yahoo.com:address2:some_details2
email2@yahoo.com:address3:some_details3
```

I am trying to read this file and split it into two folders (gmail.com and yahoo.com), and then write each  row to a unique file named after the email-ID. My code below works, but it is very slow. Can someone pls help me make this faster and more effecient? Would be appreciated.

```
#/bin/sh
grep -hv -P "[^[:ascii:]]" * |
awk -F":" '
    {
        if ($1 ~ /^[[:alnum:]_.+-]+@[[:alnum:]_.-]+\.[[:alnum:]]/ && NF>1 && $NF!="")
        {
            split($1, arr, "@")
            system("mkdir -p "tolower(arr[2]))
            print $0 >> tolower(arr[2])"/"tolower(arr[1])
        }
    }'
```

PS: the regex is a basic check to ensure the email address is valid. I am not doing a overly heavy check. At first I thought the regex is making my code slower, but not really. Even without the regex the code is super slow. I think the I/O is making this slow. How do we improve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mostly spawning a new subshell to call mkdir once per input line that's making your code run so slow. Do something like this instead:

```
filename = tolower(arr[1])
dirname = tolower(arr[2])
if ( !seen[dirname]++ ) {
    system("mkdir -p \047" dirname "\047")
}
print > (dirname "/" filename)
```

so you only spawn a subshell to call mkdir once per directory.

Note that unless you're using GNU awk you'll hit a "too many open files" error when you've created about a dozen output files and even with GNU awk that'll get slower the more output files you have open so that may also be impacting your codes performance. The common solution for that is to sort your input file by email address first and then close the current output file every time the email address (new output file name) changes.

Given that, here's how I'd really write your program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

grep -hv -P '[^[:ascii:]]' "${@:--}" |
sort -t':' -k1,1 -s |
awk -F':' '
    !($1 ~ /^[[:alnum:]_.+-]+@[[:alnum:]_.-]+\.[[:alnum:]]/ && NF>1 && $NF!="") { next }
    { curr = tolower($1) }
    curr != prev {
        close(out)
        split(curr, arr, /@/)
        filename = arr[1]
        dirname = arr[2]
        if ( !seen[dirname]++ ) {
            system("mkdir -p \047" dirname "\047")
        }
        out = dirname "/" filename
        prev = $1
    }
    { print > out }
'
```

I used GNU sort above for `-s` for "stable sort", if you don't have that and care about relative order of input lines for a given email address being retained in the output, there's other ways to handle that, e.g. `awk -v OFS=':' '{print NR, $0}' | sort -t':' -k2,2 -k1,1n | cut -d':' -f2-`.

Comment: Hello @Ed. thanks for helping again. I get an error:    grep: Invalid character class name

Comment: Ah, so THAT is why you had `-P` in your grep call. I just copied the code you had for that but got rid of the `-P` as I didn't see a use for it, I've added it back now.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
awk -F'[@:]' '{system("mkdir -p \047"$2"\047");f=$2"/"$1;print>>f;close(f)}' file
```

`-F'[@:]'` sets the input field delimiter to either `@` or `:` which gives use the following records:

```
email1 gmail.com address0 some_details0
email2 gmail.com address1 some_details1
email1 yahoo.com address2 some_details2
email2 yahoo.com address3 some_details3
```

The output filename is simply the second field + '/' + first field when records are split like that. `print >> $2"/"$1` will append the current record to that file. If it doesn't exist awk will create it.

`close(f)` after using it to make sure we'll not run out of file descriptors when the input file contains (too) many different domains and thereby output files.